# the correct way to show and hide frames in java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

My Java program has a number of `JFrame`s and a main frame with some buttons. When the user clicks on each button the related frame is showed. What is the correct way to show and hide these frames?

Just `setVisible(true);` and `setVisible(false);`?

Comment: Are you encountering any problems in implementing?

Comment: @ExtremeCoders what problem may happen ?!!!

Comment: The code is well and good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For showing a JFrame, setVisible(true) is the correct (and besides the deprecated show()-method) also the only way of making it visible.

For hiding a JFrame, setVisible(false) is correct (and again besides the deprecated hide() again the only way).

Depending on if you plan to eventually reuse the frame (show it again in future) you may additionally want to additionally call dispose() *if you will not show the frame again*. This is escpecially important if you expect the JVM to exit automatically after the last window has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this the correct way of showing and hiding frames.  It is worth bearing in mind however that, assuming a reference to the `JFrame` still exists, the object remains in memory.  Hiding it is therefore not the same as unloading it completely.

Comment: the problem you mentioned is simply solved by not creating a reference: `new frame().setVisible(true);`